# How to restart a docker container using slack/grafana or any other automated way?

Tags: docker, automation, devops, grafana, slack

I want to restart my docker container which is created using docker-compose whenWe receive an alert from grafana on slack.

The metrics are on my server endpoint url/metrics.json, which I am exporting to prometheus and sending alerts to slack.

Is there any easy way to restart the container during that alert?

Comment: Why you can't use Docker `HEALTHCHECK` directly on the container level?

Comment: @JanGaraj because the metrics are from other container and need to restart other. Example-  container B exposes some metrics about overall process and if value remains 0 for 10 minutes, I need to restart container A.

Answer (score 0):

> The metrics are on my server endpoint url/metrics.json, which I am exporting to prometheus and sending alerts to slack.

If you are already using Alertmanger with Prometheus, use the [prometheus-am-executor](https://github.com/imgix/prometheus-am-executor):

> The prometheus-am-executor is a HTTP server that receives alerts from the Prometheus Alertmanager and executes a given command with alert details set as environment variables.

You configure it as a receiver in your `alertmanager.yml`. Route your alert to this receiver in addition to your preexisting receivers:

```
receivers:
- name: 'alertmanager_executor'
  webhook_configs:
  - url: 'http://alertmanager.executor:8080'
```

And on the receiver's end, configure it to restart your container when it receives an alert with your desired labels:

```
listen_address: ":8080"
commands:
 - cmd: /usr/bin/docker restart [container]
   match_labels:
     "restart_docker": true
```

You could also configure it to run a script instead, to perform other actions:

```
listen_address: ":8080"
commands:
 - cmd: /usr/sbin/restart-containers.sh
   match_labels:
     "restart_docker": true
```

If you've set it up properly, when your alert fires, the command will be run to restart your docker container.